# What is the difference between CloudBlob subclasses?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

Looks like [CloudBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.aspx) has 3 subclasses you can use to get data in and out of Azure Storage.  Here's the (very sparse) documentation:

- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.[CloudBlockBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.aspx)

  - > Represents a blob that is uploaded as a set of blocks.
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.[CloudAppendBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudappendblob.aspx):

  - > Represents an append blob, a type of blob where blocks of data are always committed to the end of the blob.
- Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.[CloudPageBlob](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudpageblob.aspx)

  - > Represents a Microsoft Azure page blob.

I've been using `CloudBlockBlob` to upload/download pdfs and images, and everything seems to be working.  I can't seem to find a page that explains what these classes do.

Under what circumstances should I use `CloudAppendBlob` and `CloudPageBlob`?

Comment: CloudAppendBlob UploadFromByteArray Hangs or Thread Does not Return but file is fully written to the blob store.  single-writer scenarios.   This is the question and doc you are looking for. Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudAppendBlob

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found the page I was looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction

- CloudBlockBlob:

  - > Block blobs are ideal for storing text or binary files, such as documents and media files.
- CloudAppendBlob:

  - > Append blobs are similar to block blobs in that they are made up of blocks, but they are optimized for append operations, so they are useful for logging scenarios.
- CloudPageBlob:

  - > Page blobs can be up to 1 TB in size, and are more efficient for frequent read/write operations. Azure Virtual Machines use page blobs as OS and data disks.

Comment: They may have moved the content to this page...  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction